# Google spreadsheet scripts remote install?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to install a set of scripts to many google spreadsheets. Is there any API that I can install scripts remotely? Or I have to manually install all the scripts manually?

Comment: I assume you mean google-apps-script, maybe change your tags? There is a shared library feature in google apps script, but you would still need to add code to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the script editor attached to a specific spreadsheet remotely. Many functions can be run on the spreadsheet remotely using **SpreadsheetApp.openById(** Spreadsheet Key **)**

Alternatively, you can build libraries and refer to those libraries from within the sheet.